# Python smtplib many sockets in TIME_WAIT

Tags: sockets, smtplib

I have code working under Python 3.6 with [Python smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html). After sending 20 or so mails, I see with `netstat -nap`, many outbound connections remain open in the `TIME_WAIT` state for a few minutes then clear.

If I scale this up to thousands of messages, do I risk exhausting socket resources on the server?

I expect this is usual socket behavior for this code library, given its simple approach to creating and destroying the connection.

Is it possible to configure sockets to be reused, for example somehow by setting `SO_REUSEADDR` for the library's socket connections?

I'm using the library to interact directly with a remote destination, rather than buffering via an MTA, because I want to know the message was accepted immediately (i.e. no `smtplib.SMTPException` raised).

Comment: `TIME_WAIT` is perfectly normal (see [Debugging TCP/IP](https://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/debugging-tcp.html)), especially on the client side. And no, you will not exhaust resources on the server side. All connections will be on a single IP:port on the server side. Using `SO_REUSEADDR` won't make a difference if the client library uses ephemeral ports on the client side (which it should be), since each connection will be on a different client port.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the client side uses ephemeral ports. The number of `TIME_WAIT` ports open on the client hits around 2300 during a load test, then gradually comes back down.

Comment: That is normal behavior if you make a lot of connections in a short amount of time. Look at the state diagram in the article I linked to in my previous comment. If the client is the first one to close a socket connection (which is usually the case), it ends up in `TIME_WAIT`. The OS takes a few minutes to release the local IP:Port so it can be used again. Also see [TIME_WAIT and its design implications for protocols and scalable client server systems](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/01/time-wait-and-its-design-implications-for-protocols-and-scalable-servers.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Not sure if I can add kudos for a comment, am looking now :-)

Comment: comments can be upvoted